# Android ListView performitemclick

Tags: android, listview, click

I'm facing some difficulties when I try to use the `performItemClick` function of the `ListView`.
All I want to do is to perform a click programatically in the second item of the list.
How can I do that?  I tried something like:

```
pairedDeviceView.performItemClick(pairedDeviceView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, pairedDeviceView.getAdapter().getItemId());
```

where should I change?

Comment: Try this `pairedDeviceView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null).performClick();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mList.performItemClick(
        mList.getAdapter().getView(mActivePosition, null, null),
        mActivePosition,
        mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
```

Where mActivePosition is your click position! All the best! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
 mList.performItemClick(
            mList.getChildAt(1), //index started from 0, second item's index is 1
            1,
            mList.getAdapter().getItemId(1));
```